# Is there a away to pass lifecycle hook as a param to a HOC in React?

Tags: reactjs, high-order-component

I'm trying to create a wrapper HOC where I could select which lifecycle hook to pass. I have tried the following HOC:

```
const HOC = lifeCycleHook => WrappedComponent => {
  return class OriginalComponent extends React.Component {
    lifeCycleHook
    render(){
      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  }
}

export default HOC;
```

The component to wrap the original component with:

```
import React from 'react';
import HOC from './helpers/hoc';
import componentDidMount from './helpers/componentDidMount';

const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>;

export default HOC(componentDidMount)(Home);
```

and finally the lifecycle Hook:

```
import React from 'react';

function componentDidMount(){
  console.log('Test')
}

export default componentDidMount;
```

EDIT: No compilation errors are thrown, but the console log doesn't fire to print the 'Test'

Comment: Do you have a real context where would you need this? Like an real example? Just so I can understand better

Comment: Nothing in particular, was just playing around with HOCs and noticed that I couldn't implement the idea

Comment: Maybe you can't do that because there is no need to do that. You can just pass a prop to the component and call that prop in `componentDidMount`

Comment: I think you missed the point here. componentDidMount, is just an example. I'm trying to find a way where I can pass a different lifecycle hook, not to pass a prop to  specifically componentDidMount

Comment: I think Oblosys answer is good, you should test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`recompose`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) package can do this for you. Here's the example from the [`lifecycle`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle) helper:

```
const PostsList = ({ posts }) => (
  <ul>{posts.map(p => <li>{p.title}</li>)}</ul>
)

const PostsListWithData = lifecycle({
  componentDidMount() {
    fetchPosts().then(posts => {
      this.setState({ posts });
    })
  }
})(PostsList);
```